# BigQuery query only loading one row - what am I missing?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
Hi, I'd like to use the query below but it doesn't work well. (It only load 1 row from the table) Is there any error or missing things on the query below?

SELECT *
FROM `a`
WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
  SELECT MAX(REPORT_DATE)
  FROM `a`
  WHERE DATE >= '2023-01-01' AND DATE <= '2023-12-31'
)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM `b`
WHERE REPORT_DATE = (
  SELECT MAX(REPORT_DATE)
  FROM `b`
  WHERE DATE >= '2022-01-01' AND DATE <= '2022-12-31'
)
```

Also putted 'CAST' function on every data type column (REPORT_DATE, DATA_DATE) but it didn't work.